# В массив1 не добавляются значения массива2 в цикле. По одной из задач с leetcode

Tags: java, массивы

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       int[] test1 = {1,2,3,0,0,0};
       int[] test2 = {2,5,6};
       Main main = new Main();
       main.merge(test1, test1.length, test2, test2.length);
   }
   public void merge(int[] nums1, int m, int[] nums2, int n) {

       int counterN = 0;
       
       for(int j = m; j < n; j++){
           nums1[j] = nums2[counterN];
           counterN++;}

       for (int i:
            nums1) {
           System.out.println(i);

       }
```

Подскажите, почему в цикле

```
for nums1[j] = nums2[counterN];
```

не добавляет в массив `nums1` вместо нулей значения из массива `nums2`?
То есть output получается [1,2,3,0,0,0], хотя предполагал, что будет [1,2,3,2,5,6].

По условию задачи `m` и `n` - это длины массивов `nums1` и `nums2`.
У `nums1` реальная `length` на входе в метод m+n, реальная m = 3, n = 3, m+n = 6.

Нулями в массиве `nums1` заменены "пустые" ячейки, в которые предполагается в дальнейшем записать числа из массива `nums2`.

Спасибо!

Comment: При вызове метода `merge` у вас `m = 6` и `n = 3`. Поэтому в цикл от 6 до 3 вы никогда не зайдете.

Comment: Да, сейчас увидел, спасибо! . Это моя ошибка,  в моем решении в ИДЕ. Но Литкод тоже не его принимает, хотя у них при передаче в метод m=3. Вот цитата из тесткейса к задаче "Input: nums1 = [1,2,3,0,0,0], m = 3, nums2 = [2,5,6], n = 3
Output: [1,2,2,3,5,6]
Explanation: The arrays we are merging are [1,2,3] and [2,5,6].
The result of the merge is [1,2,2,3,5,6] with the underlined elements coming from nums1." При запуске там, output [0,0,0,1,2,3]

Comment: Судя по примеру, длины даются без учёта нулей, то есть, `n = m = 3`. Может, тогда идти надо до до `n + m`?

Comment: Вы хотите получить `[1,2,3,2,5,6]` или `[1,2,2,3,5,6]`? Без условия задачи сложно понять, что подразумевается под слиянием двух массивов.

Answer (score 0):

Для простого добавления элементов второго массива в первый после `m` элементов достаточно переписать цикл и отсортировать *заполненный* первый массив (почему-то такое решение принимается):

```java
import static java.util.Arrays.sort;

public void merge(int[] a, int m, int[] b, int n) {
    for (int i = m, j = 0; i < a.length;) {
        a[i++] = b[j++];
    }
    sort(a);
}
```

Если "читерское" использование встроенной / библиотечной сортировки не допускается, как по требованиям к производительности (сложность равна `O((m + n) log (m + n))`), так и по морально-этическим соображениям, следует поискать более быстрое линейное решение, например, за счёт использования промежуточного массива длиной `m + n`, содержимое которого затем будет скопировано в исходный первый массив:

```java
public void merge(int[] a, int m, int[] b, int n) {
    // создаем промежуточный массив
    int[] c = new int[m + n]; // or a.length
    
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    // записываем по очереди минимальные элементы из a и b, пока один из них не закончится
    while (j < m && k < n) {
        if (a[j] < b[k]) {
            c[i++] = a[j++];
        } else {
            c[i++] = b[k++];
        }
    }
    // копируем остаток первого массива если нужно
    while (j < m) {
        c[i++] = a[j++];
    }
    // копируем остаток второго массива если нужно
    while (k < n) {
        c[i++] = b[k++];
    }
    // перезаписываем содержимое исходного "большого" массива
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        a[i] = c[i];
    }
}
```